# Node.js convert arabic to question marks in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, callback

Here is my object :

```
var response = {
   "statusCode": 301,
    "headers": {
        'location': "resized/used_car/2018/9/18/829139/pictures/3880821/slide_show_٢٠١٨٠٩١٢_١١١١٤٤.jpg"
     },
     "body": "",
     "isBase64Encoded": true
};
callback(null, response);
```

It converts `"resized/used_car/2018/9/18/829139/pictures/3880821/slide_show_٢٠١٨٠٩١٢_١١١١٤٤.jpg"` to "resized/used_car/2018/9/18/829139/pictures/3880821/slide_show_????????_??????.jpg"

How can I fix it?

Comment: Give it a try adding the encoding on the response object, like this: `"encoding": "charset='charset=utf-8'"`

Comment: let me check it

Comment: @LucasCosta can you please tell how to add it in above response object

Comment: need to set it in header or body?

Comment: In header @HaseebAhmad

Comment: not wroking :(...